# Android Room database SqliteException not clear

Tags: android, android-room, sqliteexception

I am getting this error in my Google play console.

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForCursorWindow (Native Method)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow (SQLiteConnection.java:1196)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow (SQLiteSession.java:838)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow (SQLiteQuery.java:62)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow (SQLiteCursor.java:165)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount (SQLiteCursor.java:152)
> at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition (AbstractCursor.java:232)
> at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst (AbstractCursor.java:271)
> at in.vasudev.htmlreader.fragments.database.ScrollDao_Impl$7.call (ScrollDao_Impl.java)
> at in.vasudev.htmlreader.fragments.database.ScrollDao_Impl$7.call (ScrollDao_Impl.java)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbxl.call$bridge (zzbxl.java)
> at androidx.room.CoroutinesRoom$Companion$execute$$inlined$suspendCancellableCoroutine$lambda$1.invokeSuspend (CoroutinesRoom.java:5)
> at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith (BaseContinuationImpl.java)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run (DispatchedTask.java:88)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:919)
> Blockquote

Here is the implementation of my Room database Dao

```
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy
import androidx.room.Query

@Dao
interface ScrollDao {

    @Query("SELECT * from scroll_data WHERE url LIKE :url LIMIT 1")
    suspend fun scrollInfoItem(url: String): ScrollInfoItem?

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(item: ScrollInfoItem)

    @Query("DELETE FROM scroll_data WHERE url LIKE :url")
    suspend fun delete(url: String)

    @Query("DELETE FROM scroll_data")
    suspend fun deleteAll()
}
```

Can somebody explain why am I getting this error? Thanks

Comment: Can you add the code for db calls? Because dao queries looks fine. Or even the function from ```ScrollDao_Impl``` at the line number shown in the stack trace.

Comment: Also add what version of room database you are using . Meanwhile , try changing the versions of Room Database , the log stack sometimes shows different output for different versions of room database.

Comment: ScrollDa_Impl is generated file. We can't change it. I am using Room 2.3.0

Comment: Try to change `version` of DB and Please add code of your `Database` class and code for calling queries.